# Unable to detect empty paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using the following code to check for an empty paragraph but it never returns true. Why?

```
var isEmpty = pageChildren[i].outerHTML.toUpperCase() === "<P></P>";
var isSpace = pageChildren[i].outerHTML.toUpperCase() === "<P> </P>";
var isNbsp = pageChildren[i].outerHTML.toUpperCase() === "<P>&NBSP;</P>";
if(!isEmpty && !isSpace && !isNbsp){
   //do something
}else{
   //do something else
}
```

This is a copy paste of what IE8 debug tools tells me is in the outerHTML: `"<P></P>"`

This is being read from an iFrame so i need to remove the `<p></p>` tags also as the function above this triggers off of the number of children elements in the body of the frame.

Additionally this runs in an HTA application on IE only. The userbase/configuration is highly controlled.

Comment: I'd use innerHTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML

Comment: So how would i strip all occurances of <p></p>, <p> </p>, and <p>&nbsp;</p> from my string. I've tried string.replace with no luck and general consensus seems to be that regex shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure your object is a paragraph, you should use [innerHTML](http://www.google.com/search?q=MDN%20innerhtml) instead :

```
var isEmpty = pageChildren[i].innerHTML.trim().length==0;
```

(note that the MDN [proposes a replacement for IE8 which lacks trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)).

You could also use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText) but the downside is that you have to do a different test for IE.

Comment: Thank You. you achieved in 1 line what i couldn't in 4

Answer (score 1):

Since [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) isn't supported by all browsers, I suggest removing all spaces with RegEx:

```
var isEmpty =
    (pageChildren[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) ? true : false;
```

Comment: I'd try `.replace(/\s/g, '')`, as `{space}` doesn't match tabs and newlines.

Comment: Would this also remove the empty <p></p> tags? of does it just remove the space character.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE < 9 prepends a carriage return, line feed to the outerHTML result, so for example `pageChildren[i].outerHTML.toUpperCase() === '\r\n<P></P>'` returns true for an empty `p` element.